# TFS auto deployment on Checking in files

Tags: deployment, tfs, publishing

I am new to Team Foundation Server and trying to setup process which automatically publishes files to ftp server once I check in files. Do we have any easy trick to do that in TFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use TFS build for that. Create a Continuous Integration build ( see URL below) and setup the drop location for the build.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh395023(v=vs.110).aspx

After that see below URL on how to upload the build to FTP from the drop location.

http://jpadda.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/tfs-2010-upload-build-from-droplocation-to-ftp-activity/